# The Name of a Function in C

Tags: c, function, prototype

I know this question sound stupid but please answer it.

Let us say we have `int A(int num);` as a function prototype.

What would we refer to as the name of the function?  `int A(int num)` or `A`?

Also does the body of the function the part at the top  of the definition?

```
int A(int num){        <-- Does the body include this?

    return num * num;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: `A` is the name, `int A(int num);` is the prototype.

Comment: As a minor point, `return` is not a function and there's no need to be explicit about the priority of anything, so drop the parentheses. It's just `return num * num;`.

Comment: @unwind okay changed i t:)

Answer (score 4):

Normally you'd go with just "A" as the name of the function; as you said, `int A(int num)` is its prototype; the body is what the function does, so here just `return (num * num);`.  When referencing a function in a language that allows overloads, you might use the prototype instead of the name, however.

Answer (score 4):

The **name** of `int A(int num)` is `A`.

The first part, `int`, describe the return type of the function, then we have the name of the function, `A`, and finally a list of parameters the function accepts `(int num)`. In this case it is a single parameter of type **int**

The **body** of a function, is the code which actually performs the functionality of the function. Basically its the code within the curly brackets: `{ }`

```
int A(int num){        

    return(num * num);    //this is the body
}
```